# Filling missing rows two data frames

Tags: r, missing-data

I have two large data sets. One is an old one and the second one is about the same as the first one. The difference is that the second one has new rows, updated `Value` and missing rows compared to the first data set. 
I would like to keep everything in the new data set and fill it with the missing rows (combinations of `Date` and `Code`) that are present in the old data set. The order is not important.

Old data set:

```
              Date Code Value 
        2015-10-01   1   145
        2015-10-01   1   175 
        2015-11-01   6   112 
        2015-12-01   2   160 
        2016-01-01   6   124
        2016-01-01   6   572
        2016-02-01   5   160 
        2016-02-01   1   574
```

New data set:

```
              Date Code Value 
        2015-10-01   1   145
        2015-10-01   2   1452
        2015-11-01   6   125 
        2015-12-01   2   160 
        2016-01-01   6   1501
        2016-01-01   6   572
        2016-03-01   9   452
        2016-03-01   7   500
```

Output:

```
              Date Code Value 
        2015-10-01   1   145
        2015-10-01   2   1452
        2015-11-01   6   125 
        2015-12-01   2   160 
        2016-01-01   6   1501
        2016-01-01   6   572
        2016-03-01   9   452
        2016-03-01   7   500
        2015-10-01   1   175 
        2016-02-01   5   160 
        2016-02-01   1   574
```

When there is no matching combination of `Date` and `Code` the corresponding row from the old data set should be added.
In the output, the last three rows come from the old data set. I have looked at different posts without luck to find what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the anti_join function from the dplyr library to find all the rows in the old_df that doesn't exist in new_df

```
df <- anti_join(old_df,new_df,by=c("date","code","value"))
        date code value
1 2016-01-01    6   124
2 2016-02-01    1   574
3 2016-02-01    5   160
4 2015-10-01    1   175
5 2015-11-01    6   112
final_df <- full_join(df,new_df,by=c("date","code","value"))
         date code value
1  2016-01-01    6   124
2  2016-02-01    1   574
3  2016-02-01    5   160
4  2015-10-01    1   175
5  2015-11-01    6   112
6  2015-10-01    1   145
7  2015-10-01    2  1452
8  2015-11-01    6   125
9  2015-12-01    2   160
10 2016-01-01    6  1501
11 2016-01-01    6   572
12 2016-03-01    9   452
13 2016-03-01    7   500
```

Comment: `final_df <- anti_join(oldds,newds,by=c("Date", "Code"))` it almost works but it doesn't detect this line `2015-10-01    1   175 ` where only `Code` has changed. Moreover I get this warning message `joining factors with different levels, coercing to character vector`

Comment: Ok, I realise what I've done. firstly, anti_join only returns part of the answer. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: The reason why you are getting the warning is cause your date column is possibly set as factors you can change that my using as.character() on your date columns

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
key.new <- with(newds, interaction(Date, Code, Value))
key.old <- with(oldds, interaction(Date, Code, Value))
```

then

```
ind <- match(key.old, key.new, nomatch=0) == 0
```

gives you the rows from the old data set that should be added to the new
one, if I understand the question correctly.

```
> oldds[ind, ]
        Date Code Value
2 2015-10-01    1   175
3 2015-11-01    6   112
5 2016-01-01    6   124
7 2016-02-01    5   160
8 2016-02-01    1   574
```

As an aside note, it's recommended that you provide a minimal reproducible
example, including the commands to recreate the data that you're working
with e.g. the output of `dput(oldds)` and `dput(newds)` or

```
oldds <-
read.table(text='
          Date Code Value 
    2015-10-01    1   145
    2015-10-01    1   175 
    2015-11-01    6   112 
    2015-12-01    2   160 
    2016-01-01    6   124
    2016-01-01    6   572
    2016-02-01    5   160 
    2016-02-01    1   574
', header=TRUE)

newds <-
read.table(text='
          Date Code Value 
    2015-10-01    1   145
    2015-10-01    2  1452
    2015-11-01    6   125 
    2015-12-01    2   160 
    2016-01-01    6  1501
    2016-01-01    6   572
    2016-03-01    9   452
    2016-03-01    7   500
', header=TRUE)
```

Comment: Yes, the values in rows 3 and 5 have been updated in the new data set and should be kept